# Mathematical formula to find point position on various windows differ in size (width and height)

Tags: html, css, math

I have position (x,y) of point inside a rectangle which has known width and height, how to find the relative position (x1, y1) for the same point on another rectangle have different size (height1, windth1), what is the mathematical formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used an approximate mathematics formula as follow:
assume that the length and width of a rectangle are H, W respectively, and such point location is (x, y). The other rectangle dimensions (height and width) are H1, W1 respectively, so we can find that the location for the point (x1, y1) => (x * H1/H, y * W1/W)
by using (H:x, W:y) <=> (H1:x1, W1:y1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1 = new Panel();
        panel2 = new Panel();
        // panel1
        panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        panel1.Location = new Point(22, 29);
        panel1.Name = "panel1";
        panel1.Size = new Size(159, 120);
        panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        panel1.Click += panel1_Click;
        // panel2
        panel2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        panel2.Location = new Point(187, 29);
        panel2.Name = "panel2";
        panel2.Size = new Size(273, 120);
        panel2.TabIndex = 1;
    }

    private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point panel1Point = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        PrintPoint(panel1Point);
        Point panel1PointToScreen = panel1.PointToScreen(Cursor.Position);
        Point point2Point = panel2.PointToClient(panel1PointToScreen);
        PrintPoint(point2Point);
    }

    private void PrintPoint(Point point)
    {
        var msg = string.Format("X:{0}, Y:{1}", point.X, point.Y);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
```

> More Information
>   [getting mouse position of different control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088991/getting-mouse-position-of-different-control)